# How to access schema and its objects outside the Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 DBs in Azure,

DB1, 
DB2

I created schema in DB1 as DB1 and created some tables under the schema, like

DB1.table1
DB1.table2

My doubt is, from DB2 we can access the table with help of 
[DB1].DB1.table1 rite?

but can i access like  [schema].[table]. in my example DB1.table1.

Is there any option for that.

Comment: Are the databases on the same server?

Comment: yes @Tom thy are in same server. They are not synonym, but my doubt is how thy accessing in 2 part instead of 3 part.

Comment: If they are the same server why not just use the "Use" statement at the top of the query? Use DB1 Select * from [schema].[table]?

Comment: we cannot use "Use" statement in the join or SP rite.

Comment: What do you mean by Join? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but you know you can use `SELECT * FROM DB1.schema.table` from DB2 right?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid from join with DB2

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes i know we can use SELECT * FROM DB1.schema.table,  My question is, in my Procedure they have accessing the table from DB1 like SELECT * FROM schema.table. I want to know how this is possible.

Comment: If it's not a synonym or a view, and if there isn't some kind of replication going on, then I don't know. Are you saying that if you insert a record in the other table you'll instantly see it in this one?

Comment: I agree with Nick, I don't really get what you are trying to do unless you mean you are wanting to write a join statement across two databases to find some data. Unless you use one of the above methods mentioned (Synonym,view) you will need to use a fully qualified table name.

Comment: I think they are saying there is an existing system where this appears to happen. But I think there is some kind of misunderstanding

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes this is happening in existing system, where they accessing table which is bound to one schema in DB1 from another DB2 without using the DB part in query. They just using the schema name from DB1,   IS there any kind of Permission or roles which we can use to do like this.

Comment: No there isn't. There must be some kind of misunderstanding, or there is some other process occurring.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I found about the above process happening in my existing environment. 

My Current environment is Azure SQL Databases, in which cross database queries are not directly supported so we cannot use 3 part in query to access table.

They have created External Data Source for DB1 in DB2 to access DB1 data inside DB2.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can query a table in another Database using the following method:

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM [DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName] as tbl
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM northwind.dbo.orders where id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Synonym` like the following:

```
Use DB2
Create synonym Syn_SomeName
for  [DB1].DB1.table1
```

You can then run a select statement from your second database like:

```
Select * from Syn_SomeName
```

More information of Synonyms can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine), however this been said you would not want to create a synonym for every table only for tables that people may have to query a lot.

Comment: No need to create a synonym - in fact, you are already accessing the DB1 table from DB2 with a three-part name in order to create the synonym

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but am working in the client environment, they have been accessing tables across DB with the format i asked [schema].[table]. I also checked they are not using Synonyms for this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, This is true but I believe the OP was asking how to query without having to write a  three-part name, Although they will have to, to create the synonym one it is set up they don't have to keep writing it out?